# how to delete records from database in c#

Tags: c#, .net

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    int index = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    Model1.DevicesInfo_Tbl Device_Info_Obj = new Model1.DevicesInfo_Tbl();

    Device_Info_Obj.DevicesName.Remove(index, index);

    E_Shop_DB_Obj.SaveChanges();
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

I can't understand where my code is wrong.  Compiler got an error when arrive to `Device_Info_Obj.DevicesName.Remove(index, index);`. How can i fix it?
I want to delete selected row in Data Base.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Forklift An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Project1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: In your DevicesInfoObj constructor, you need to instantiate DevicesName. Either that or your DeviceInfoObj object is null. Debugging should show you which is the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: So, why don't you set `debug-exceptions` to `throw` and then just run your code? It will show where the issue

Comment: @T.S. Please tell me a way that delete a row in sql server DB

Comment: `DELETE FROM [schema].[table] WHERE [column] = <value>`. Do you realize that we can't help you because your question is vague?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is already vague, but the way you name the objects doesn't make it better.

I assume that E_Shop_DB_Obj is your database context. You want to remove an object from table DevicesInfo_Tbl. And it looks like DevicesName is a field (of type string) in your table.

What you are doing now is removing characters from the field (of type string) Device_Info_Obj.DevicesName. Since you created Device_Info_Obj it seems that DevicesName is null. That is why you get the NullReference exception.

Anyway, to delete an object you'll need to remove the object from the context:

```
        using (var E_Shop_DB_Obj = new Model())
        {
            var item = E_Shop_DB_Obj.DevicesInfo_Tbl.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == index);
            // Test if item is not null
            E_Shop_DB_Obj.DevicesInfo_Tbl.Remove(item);
            E_Shop_DB_Obj.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first find the object with a key value and then you can remove it

```
var item = E_Shop_DB_Obj.DevicesInfo_Tbl.Find(index);//ASSUMING index IS THE KEY
E_Shop_DB_Obj.DevicesInfo_Tbl.Remove(item);
E_Shop_DB_Obj.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: when i reopen the project the item that i deleted back.

Comment: Cant help more if you cant give your other code pieces.